# Java program keeps getting bigger

Tags: java

I've written a program in Java that detects when the computer it's being run on is idle. When the idle time is reset (in other words, the mouse or keyboard is used), the program locks the computer. This program is designed to run when the computer starts and continue to run while the machine is on. My problem is that the program takes up more and more space as it runs longer. I don't see any reason why it should; there's nothing like an ArrayList that's being added to constantly. The program "expands" in memory by about 10 megabytes per hour. Is there some sort of garbage collection I should be doing?

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to identify which objects are growing in your program?  JVisualVM is free and ships with the JDK

Comment: I haven't; I'll give that a shot...

Comment: I guess you are relying on some native call. Are you sure that all ressources are freed when not used ? Are you sure you are not calling over and over the same ressource without releasing it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the heap size to a lower value... the garbage collector should then kick-in earlier. Manually calling `System.gc()` from time to time should also solve your problem. If this results in OutOfMemory exception after a while and/or the memory is still constantly increasing, then you really have a memory leak somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you even have a problem. 10 MB really isn't that large. It could be that the garbage collector simply hasn't "decided" to run in a while. You can try to call the GC directly by calling System.gc(), but really, I wouldn't worry too much unless you're running out of memory or having performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Any time your program uses the `new` operator the runtime will allocate new memory that may not be freed until the garbage collector decides it is time to reclaim available space.  So even if you are not "leaking" memory by adding to a collection that is never cleared you are still using memory and your usage will grow over time.

Consider eliminating calls to `new` (e.g. by reusing existing objects) or tuning the heap size settings on the JVM to initiate the garbage collector more frequently if memory consumption is a concern.